# Do not allow Firebase node listing

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

**TL;DR;**

users **can't** read/write at `root/chat-rooms/`

users **can** read/write at `root/chat-rooms/guid-id`

**Full version:**

I have the following Firebase structure:

root > chat-rooms > room-id-guid (1000+) > messages under each room-id-guid

I don't want my users to authenticate with user/pass; as long as you can get into the room through the UI (links are generated on the server, and only a couple of rooms are available to any given user), you can read/write.

What I don't want is for users to be able to list all of the room-id-guids (e.g. through the developer console) and read/write to the room bypassing the UI.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, simply disable reading at the root or list-level of your Firebase, but permit reading at the specific room level:

```
{
  ".read": "false",
  ".write": "false",
  "chat-rooms": {
    "$guid": {
      ".read": "true"
    }
  }
}
```